# Проверка на отсутствие одинаковых TabPage`ов

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Мне необходимо проверить все TabPage`ы в TabControl, и если среди них не был найден ни один с определенным текстом, то выполнять на определенное действие.

Пробовал так:

```
foreach (TabPage item in editorTabControl.TabPages)
{
    if (item.Text != filesList.SelectedItems[0].Text)
    {
    }
}
```

И условие выполняется при первой же станице.

Comment: Использую WinForms, нужно перебирать табы и проверять текст в их заголовках.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Пока все логично. Условие стоит на *неравенство*. Сомневаюсь что текст первой вкладки в коллекции совпадает с выбранным.

Comment: Что сделать-то хотите в итоге?

Comment: Нужно проверить существует ли TabPage с определенным текстом, например "test" и если существует, то ничего не делать, а если нет, то выполнять другое действие. Я никак не могу придумать как реализовать условие.

Comment: ну так поменяйте условие на *равенство* для начала, раз уж *если есть, то выполнить*

Comment: Я делаю блокнот с вкладками и деревом проекта, сделал открытие файлов, но мне нужно запретить открывать один и тот же файл по 100 раз т.к создаётся слишком много вкладок.

Comment: Все уточнения должны быть в самом вопросе. Написал возможный вариант, пробуйте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методами LiNQ:

```
if (editorTabControl.TabPages.Cast<TabPage>().Any(p => p.Name == filesList.SelectedItems[0].Text)
{
     //для примера активируем вкладку по имени
     editorTabControl.SelectTab(filesList.SelectedItems[0].Text);
}
```

`Cast<T>()` в данном случае необходимо вызвать, чтобы привести специализированную коллекцию к обобщенному перечислению.